# Using an email without email services

Tags: command-line, email

I know that I can send email with the `mail` command. Something like `echo “Hello world” | mail -s “Hello world” foo@bar.com` would do the trick.

But, given that I and a partner are online, how can we communicate with each other receiving and sending email only using the command line?

The idea is to send and receive emails messages between two computers (with known IPs, and eventually with dynamic DNS), so that each can monitor the work of the other, and that without connecting through an email provider like yahoo.com, gmail, or hotmail.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you don't need/want email at all. Perhaps some kind of collaborative tool? See etherpad for example.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in theory each of you just has to put a mail server (sendmail, postfix, etc.) on your system, which does the following processing:

- When a mail is to be sent, it queues the email to be sent and tries (sometimes multiple times) to connect to the remote mail server to send the email.
- When a mail is received from another server, it accepts the email and puts it in your mailbox (or runs it through a filter like Spam Assassin)

In practice, unless both of you are using a business Internet connection or have an online web host, the email port (SMTP, port 25) is blocked to not allow you to send email -- too many selfish, greedy spammers abused SMTP to plaster the internet with their ads; home ISPs finally had to block it.

The arms race went like this:

- People would get normal hosting accounts and use them to spam everyone.
- Everyone would complain to the hosting provider, forcing them to kick off their spammers [The ISPs which tried to be spammer-friendly were in due course blacklisted; look up the history of AGIS and the RBL for more information]
- Soon, any respectable hosting provider would immediately kick off anyone who tried to spam
- The spammers, in turn, started sending their spam by putting viruses and malware on people's computers which would take over the computer so it would send out spam
- After a while, ISPs had to make it impossible for their home computers to directly send out email to send spam
- Recently, the Spamhaus project (a black list of spammers) was attacked because they would not remove a spammer-friendly ISP (Cyber Bunker)

ISP issues aside, there's also the matter of registering a domain with DNS, and setting up a DNS server to give the domain what's called a "MX" record.

Comment: About the DNS issue, there's nothing preventing you from installing your own DNS server and setup the records for the target server, using a unused TLD (i like `.lan`, but maybe it's used now). Tell `bind` (or whatever you use) about a real-word DNS server so you can still access the rest of the web. Once you edited your `/etc/resolv.conf` to use `localhost` you should be done !

Comment: RFC2606 allows ".test", ".invalid", ".example", and ".localhost" as guaranteed non-global TLDs.

Answer (score 1):

To use the mail command to send messages you absolutely need a mail service but not necessarily a public one (yahoo, gamil ..etc).
**HOW** :
If you are enough privileges on the system, you can install easily the `postfix` service on your machine or the remote one or both of them.
The second step is to create mail accounts in the servers installed.
Now you can exchange emails with your partner.

**EASIER FOR CHAT** : You can create a login for your partner in your system. Then using SSH he can login to your machine. Once you're both connected using a shell, you can discover by typing the `who` command which Terminal (TTY or PTS#) is he using :

```
$ who
slimani  tty7         2014-03-16 20:25 (:0)
oracle   pts/9        2014-03-18 17:29 (localhost)
```

Supposing you are *slimani* and he is *oracle*. You can message him using this :

```
$write oracle pts/9
Hello my partner
I am connected and alive.
What do you want?
^C
```

Your partner will receive this text :

```
Message from slimani@slxpc on pts/6 at 17:32 ...
Hello my partner
I am connected and alive.
What do you want?
EOF
```